# port and deploy node.js app to windows as service

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, windows-installer

I've got a node.js application that is working on on linux. I need to deploy this to clients on a windows machine. What's the best way to package it up in an installer (or similar) and install it as a windows service. I can't assume the client machine will have node, so perhaps the installer would need to setup all npm packages (express, etc) and even install node itself. I'm open to alternative approaches that accomplish the final goal: which is is to get my node app running as a windows service on a virgin machine (no node installation, etc.)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Advanced Installer to create setup packages for Windows and I think this should be easily accomplished with it. From your requirements I think that all you need to configure into an Advanced Installer setup project is:

1. add Node.JS setup package as a prerequisite in "Prerequisites" page
2. add your Node.JS application files in "Files and Folders" page
3. add your Node.JS application in "Services" page to be installed as a service

*Note.* The Prerequisites and Services pages require at least a Professional license, but all of these can be tested with a free trial.

**EDIT**:___ [Video on how to package a Node.js app with Advanced Installer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zF63PoPYqvw).

Comment: What if the app requires files from external npm packages (and not just nodejs runtime)?